# How innocent was Newton Crosby when he took the NOVA Robotics contract?

Tags: short-circuit

In [*Short Circuit*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091949/) (1986), Newton Crosby is contracted to develop and build five robots armed with a laser that can destroy a tank. He is indignant when the military has war related applications in mind. What did he think they were going to be used for when he was building them?

Comment: Making enormous Swiss cheese?  The applications are unlimited!

Comment: Nice Real Genius reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that *cannot* be answered in canon without plain assumptions. The motives  of Crosby the years before Johnny 5 was built and then programmed by him are impossible to know.

Inside of canon:

Crosby is quite vocal about his dislike of his skills/programming/work in the use of military, but goes along with it regardless.

Outside of canon

Crosby, like many people with big ideas, but no money, are attracted to whoever will pay for them. The military offered him a way to do the work he wanted to do.

So he took it, probably just ignoring the fact, that the tech could be used to murder people.

After all, *he's not the one doing it*. His personal morals continue on unbroken.

He just designed it after all.